# Does summary() by default only return 100 observations and can I increase this?

Tags: r, summary, quanteda

Hi I am still kinda new to R and quanteda. I am working with a large corpus and want to get summary statistics of this. There is already a summary available of 7897 observations and I tried to recreate this. This should work with the summary() function but when I try this I only get the first 100 observations. Is there a way to increase this number? I looked in the R documentation of summary() but couldn't find a solution. I tried to dput() the head of my data but since it consists of very long texts this does not really work.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example: <https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example>

Comment: Can you try something like: `summary(corpus_object, n = 1000)` to get a thousand documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
summoutput <- summary(corp, n = Inf)
```